# Check if type of a mixed value is part of a mixed type

Tags: typescript

I have been running into a problem with mixed types and maybe am googling wrong in this case. Anyway I haven't found a sufficient answer yet. I am using custom types, which are a mix of different object types.
In some functions, I want to allow passing in objects of all kinds of these custom types and want to check in the function, to which of these custom types the type of the object belongs.
Please see the code below - my issue is the if-condition:

```
type TypeCollection1 = Type1 | Type2 | Type3; // these are all object types with some common keys
type TypeCollection2 = Type4 | Type5 | Type6; // these are all object types with some common keys

function doSomething(myObject: TypeCollection1 | TypeCollection2): void {
    if (myObject instanceof TypeCollection1) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Note: Please don't pick on the `instanceof` in the example code above. This is just for illustration of the issue.

I tried `typeof` and `instanceof`-combinations in many ways but it is not working at all. For now, I am helping myself by checking, if a key, that all objects of a collection have in common, is present in the object. But honestly I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

```
    if ("example_key" in myObject) {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so since there have been neither answers nor comments, I decided to post my own workaround. It's not what I was looking for, but is at least a little more convenient. Since I keep my type-definitions in separate files, I decided to add a typeguard-function to each definition file.
The drawback is, that I have to add options to the functions, whenever I enhance the type. However, since I have to change the file anyways, I can as well change two lines in the file.
So, here we go:

```
export type TypeCollection1 = Type1 | Type2 | Type3;

export function isInstanceOfTypeCollection1(object: any): object is TypeCollection1 {
    const isInstance = object instanceof Type1 || object instanceof Type2 || object instanceof Type3;
    return isInstance;
}
```

Whenever I want to check now, I only have to call the function and don't have to check for specific object-keys.